# What features accounting for more RPG depth did Skyrim add compared to Oblivion?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Morrowind was a much deeper RPG experience, Oblivion went for more action and turned out being lots of eye candy but not as much to keep me interested, it felt plastic and much of the same, and with Skyrim I'm not looking simply for more, bigger and shinier Oblivion.

Which RPG features that didn't make the cut from Morrowind to Oblivion does Skyrim get back, if any, and what other new ones does it add?

Comment: Hi @Vic, welcome to the site! Our site is based around Q&A, not discussion. If you could edit your question to be something less subjective (enjoyment of a game is *purely* subjective), such as asking what specific gameplay characteristics Skyrim retains/drops in comparison to Oblivion and Morrowind, we could likely keep it open. As stated though, it is merely soliciting opinion. Please check out the [FAQ] if you have any more questions on what's on-topic here.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, FallenAngelEyes! I've edited going for a much more objetive drill, please provide feedback.

Comment: Your question's been reopened and can now receive answers! :)

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you mentioned what you liked about Morrowind that didn't go into Oblivion.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I never finished Morrowind.  But I did play Oblivion viciously.
Skyrim offers a greater landscape than Oblivion -  by a lot.  The world is bigger, you can explore mountains/forest/caves.  While in oblivion it was pretty much... long boring plain with trees and caves every now and then.  Skyrim is much richer when it comes to terrain.
In Skyrim you can still buy a house, but now it they feel more like home.  You can actually put stuff of your own on display without having to access mods.

You can also get married. (If you own a house, your spouse will wait for you there).
The new perk system is a love or hate it.  You should build your own opinion on this. It is similar to fallout's.

Now, you are not forced to pick primary or secondary skills anymore.  You just play how you like it, and level up.  You only pick a race when you begin.  So no more classes.
Questing has changed too. Secondary quest are "random", you will never run out of extra tasks... and they are presented in a not too obvious fashion.  It is nice to walk in a tavern, hear NPCs talking about some "mystery" and following into a quest.
Which brings me to the world.

If there is something that adds immersion in this game it is the atmosphere.  When you step into the game, you feel like you are in a world that is alive and you are the new guy in town.  If you normaly get sucked into dialogs and lore.  This game is definitely for you.  (This is definitely an improvement over what I played in Morrowind).

Of course, all the mechanics that have been added/improved also affect the way you interact with the game.  For example, smithing/enchanting but you can find those all over the internet.

Comment: You do well in listing the positive points, but I find oblivion->skyrim has lost a lot too. There are no classes, only races. You can't have primary or secondary skills. Everything is a lot simpler, easier, less complex. The GUI is slower (alchemy in oblivion was lightning fast). It's not as bad as Deus Ex -> Deus Ex II, but I do experiment the same idea of console-oriented development, but luckily not taken as far.

Comment: I like your take on the immersion, it's a really big plus and it's a huge element of RPGs, even though it isn't the exact aspect I'm looking for.

Comment: Well, Vic sadly old school RPGs are hard to find.  Most of them are adapting to the console experience loosing much of what made them nice for PC before. The audience has changed much as well.  Games like morrowind can feel too tedious to the larger audience.  I feel that skyrim went tries to satisfy both ends, and obviously falls a bit short in both ends.  Some ppl might find it boring, while others (like you and me) feel like RPG elements such as crafting/enchanting should be better implemented to reward people who are willing to spend hours on them.